# function to add dicts to a nested dict that give increasing keys

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Lets say that I have an empty dictionary. How would I go about writing a function that would add other dictionaries to the empty one, giving it a key that would increase for every new dictionary added?

So it would result in something like:

```
{0: {'name': 'pork', 'cals': 100, 'pro': 10, 'sugar': 1},
 1: {'name': 'chicken', 'cals': 190, 'pro': 19, 'sugar': 19},
 2: {'name': 'beef', 'cals': 160, 'pro': 12, 'sugar': 2}}
```

Comment: Give it a shot yourself and post your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_of_dicts = dict(enumerate(list_of_dicts))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a list of the dictionaries you want to add, then use a simple for loop to add them into your dictionary:

```
result = {}
ex1 = {'name': 'pork', 'cals': 100, 'pro': 10, 'sugar': 1}
ex2 = {'name': 'chicken', 'cals': 190, 'pro': 19, 'sugar': 19}
ex3 = {'name': 'beef', 'cals': 160, 'pro': 12, 'sugar': 2}
listDict = [ex1,ex2,ex3]

for i in range(len(listDict)):
  result[i] = listDict[i]
print(result)
```

output:

```
{0: {'name': 'pork', 'cals': 100, 'pro': 10, 'sugar': 1}, 1: {'name': 'chicken', 'cals': 190, 'pro': 19, 'sugar': 19}, 2: {'name': 'beef', 'cals': 160, 'pro': 12, 'sugar': 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will help you out:

```
def add_dict(d1, out_dict):
    new_key = len(out_dict.keys())
    out_dict[new_key] = d1
    
ex1 = {'name': 'pork', 'cals': 100, 'pro': 10, 'sugar': 1}
ex2 = {'name': 'chicken', 'cals': 190, 'pro': 19, 'sugar': 19}
ex3 = {'name': 'beef', 'cals': 160, 'pro': 12, 'sugar': 2}
listDict = [ex1,ex2,ex3]

out = {}
for dict1 in listDict:
    add_dict(dict1, out)
    
print (out)
```